# HTML/CSS Dropdown problems

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

So i'm having a huge issue with my navigation. I'm trying to add a drop down menu but no matter what I try its not working out. Below is my current HTML/CSS code and if you have any idea how to fix it please help!! I also attached a picture of what i'm actually trying to make it look like.

[image: Here's what I want the drop down to look like]

Here's the HTML

```
    <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/original/xlablogoheader.gif" width="auto" height="130"/></a><span> experimental social science laboratory</span></div>



    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page.html">About</a>
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="page.html">Mission</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="page.html">Staff</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="page.html">Participants</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="page.html">Researchers</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="page.html">Connect</a>
            </li> 
        </ul>
     </div> 

    </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
/* Menu */
.menu{float:right; padding:0 20px 0 0;}
.menu ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0px;}
.menu ul * {margin:0; padding:0;}
.menu ul li {float:left; padding:0 20px 0 20px; height:35px;}
.menu ul li a{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;color:#fff; font-size:16px;}
.menu ul li.selected a{color:#000;}
.menu ul li a:hover{color:#000;} 
.menu  ul ul { display: none; position: absolute; top: 25px }  
.menu ul li:hover > ul { display: inherit; color:#000;}
```

Comment: Exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: The drop down doesn't actually show up. I can only see the main navigation correctly but when I hover over them, no drop down is visible.

Comment: Have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubko5Lxs/). Should be obvious what the problem is from hovering over `About` on that. I would have edited this one to have runable code instead, but I seem to have hit my edit limit on Q&A for the day, ho hum.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem but I just can't figure out how to fix it. I tried changing it to a button too but didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, a little bit, by adding `position: relative;` to menu class, also some other minor changes, so it works, please check this     https://jsfiddle.net/ysmr364m/